# SSL Certificate from 1&1 to an AWS EC2 instance not working

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I have a php web app running on a AWS EC2 instance with ubuntu. It's domain name comes however from 1&1 and is pointing to the AWS EC2 public IP. 
I have a SSL certificate from 1&1 on this same domain name.

When running the web page on my browser in http everything works fine. But as soon as I run it with https it's there is constant load and the page never renders.

I guess the issue is caused by my apache configuration, but I don't know what needs to be changed to make the https working fine.

Here is my mydomain.com.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mydomain/"

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_mydomain.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

By looking on internet, I found out that a ssl key has to be added into the conf file, but since I'm using an ssl certificate from 1&1 I have no key or whatsoever.

Is there anyone who knows more about it ? 
Thanks

Comment: 1&1 should provide you with the certificate files (public key, private key and certificate chain) for the SSL certificate you purchased from them. You will need to install those files on your web server and configure your server to serve HTTPS on port 443. If you don't know how to download the SSL certificate files from 1&1 I suggest you contact 1&1 support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I know not many people will run into this same issue, but we never know...

It is impossible to do this without the /ssl/cert files indeed.

Unfortunately, the 1 SSL Certificate offered by 1&1 on the ultimate packs are only made for websites hosted on 1&1. I called them, and they don't want to give me the cert files because my webpage is hosted at AWS.

Thus, there is no other option then getting an other SSL certificate. I'll probably use letsencrypt for that.

Answer (score 0):

You must have been provided with a cert and cert bundle from your CA vendor, and I am hoping you have kept the private key intact when creating the CSR for the bundle, your vhost should look something like this:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName <mywebsite>
    ServerAlias www.<mywebsite>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/<mywebsitedocroot>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

        <Directory /var/www/html/<mywebsitedocroot>>
                #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Options -Indexes
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/<mywebsitedocroot>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    ServerName <mywebsite>
    ServerAlias www.<mywebsite>
    SSLEngine On
    #SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/<mycert>.crt
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/<mycert>.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/<mycert>_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/<mycert>_com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/<mycert>_com.ca-bundle
    <Directory /var/www/html/<mywebsitedocroot>>
        #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What is essential to understand is HTTPS listens on port 443, not 80 (it is for HTTP) and the most important section (considering your situation) is:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/<mycert>_com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/<mycert>_com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/<mycert>_com.ca-bundle
```

You can ignore all the Options I have set or set it as per your need. I just grabbed the info from my website conf. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your interesting reply